# Angular one time binding without a watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with Angular's one time binding.

Let's say I want to use ngIf with one time binding, something like this:

```
<div ng-if="::showImage">
    <img src="somesource" img-preloader/>
</div>
```

In this case angular creates a watch for the expression inside the if.
Once it has been resolved to a none-undefined value the watch is removed.

If it was resolved to a truthly value only then the descendant html tree is added to the DOM and subsequently rendered.

Now this is all great but I'd really like to avoid the initial watch, just parse the expression, and if its undefined - only then set up a watch. The reason being is fairly complex in my scenario but basically I have some mechanism that temporarily disables unneeded watches...

So I was looking for alternatives to the built-in angular's one time binding and came across [angular-once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once).

Angular-once implements one-time-binding in a different way, it sets up a temp watch only if the expression is parsed to undefined, so if it resolves in the initial attempt no watch is created. Sounds great.

So I could do something like this:

```
<div once-if="showImage">
    <img src="somesource" img-preloader/>
</div>
```

But, here's the problem - apparently the descendant HTML tree is first rendered by default and then if once-if resolves to false the descendant nodes are removed from the DOM.

Here's the snippet that does it:

```
{
  name: 'onceIf',
  priority: 600,
  binding: function (element, value) {
    if (!value) {
      element.remove();
    }
  }
},
```

This is bad behavior for me, as creating the descendant tree is a no-go and results in other problems, for instance - in the above example the img will be downloaded.

So I'm looking for a way to do one-time-binding in directives like ngIf without setting up a watch if the expression parses successfully and without pre-rendering the descendant tree.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to avoid this, but for now I ended up implementing custom directives based on Angular's standard ones but with the necessary added functionality.

ngIf derived directive:

```
app.directive('watchlessIf', ['$animate', '$compile', '$parse', function($animate, $compile, $parse) {
    return {
        multiElement: true,
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 600,
        terminal: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        $$tlb: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            function valueChangedAction(value) {
                if (value) {
                    if (!childScope) {
                        $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
                            childScope = newScope;
                            clone[clone.length++] = $compile.$$createComment('end watchlessIf', $attr.watchlessIf);
                            block = {
                                clone: clone
                            };
                            $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    if (previousElements) {
                        previousElements.remove();
                        previousElements = null;
                    }
                    if (childScope) {
                        childScope.$destroy();
                        childScope = null;
                    }
                    if (block) {
                        previousElements = getBlockNodes(block.clone);
                        $animate.leave(previousElements).then(function() {
                            previousElements = null;
                        });
                        block = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            var block, childScope, previousElements;
            if ($attr.watchlessIf.startsWith("::")) {
                var parsedExpression = $parse($attr.watchlessIf)($scope);
                if (parsedExpression != null) {
                    valueChangedAction(parsedExpression);
                    return;
                }
            }

            $scope.$watch($attr.watchlessIf, valueChangedAction);
        }
    };
}]);
```

ngBind derived directive:

```
app.directive('watchlessBind', ['$compile', '$parse', function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        compile: function watchlessBindCompile(templateElement) {
            $compile.$$addBindingClass(templateElement);
            return function watchlessBindLink(scope, element, attr) {
                function valueChangedAction(value) {
                    element.textContent = (typeof value == "undefined") ? '' : value;
                }

                $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.watchlessBind);
                element = element[0];
                if (attr.watchlessBind.startsWith("::")) {
                    var parsedExpression = $parse(attr.watchlessBind)(scope);
                    if (parsedExpression != null) {
                        valueChangedAction(parsedExpression);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                scope.$watch(attr.watchlessBind, valueChangedAction);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Notes:

- Unfortunately with such approach I'll have to implement similar directives for other Angular directives as well where I'd like to support potentially watch-less one time binding.
- I'm using private angular stuff inside the directives, like the $$tlb option, although i really shouldn't...